# No Man's Sky, what decides Apollo's fate?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Note: This is about ***APOLLO***, not ***ARTEMIS***.

During the main quest line in No Man Sky there are two possible outcomes related to the character Apollo:

- he decides to go thru a portal and then disappear (implied dead like Artemis).
- he never goes thru a portal and keeps talking to you during the rest of the game (he is still forgotten as you reach the end)

Exactly what is the trigger that decides what path you get?
Most players seems to agree that this is tied to a specific dialogue that gives you the option of giving him access to a portal or refuse to do so. But usually those sources do not agree on what choice gives you what outcome.

- some say that giving Apollo the coordinates make him try to use it and die.
- some say that not giving him the coordinates causes him to try a random set of glyph and die.

I am far after the point to be able to still test this (I remember him living after giving him the coordinates but I am not sure).
So, do anyone have a final answer to this that includes actual proof? Ideally, a link to some timestamps in a let's play video that show both choices and outcomes could be sufficient.